# Get separate low and high bytes of a member of a Uint16Array

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, typed-arrays

So I have a Uint16Array in JavaScript:

```
let myArray = new Uint16Array(10)
```

Now I want to break a particular value from this array into two 8-bit values - the low and high bytes of the value.

```
myArray[5] = 300 // How to get low, high byte of 16-bit value 300?
```

The two values produced should be of the `number` type.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lower byte can be found in this way:

```
let val = myArray[5] & 0xFF;
```

Higher byte can be found in this way:

```
let val2 = (myArray[5] >> 8) & 0xFF;
```

Example:

```
> let myArray = new Uint16Array(10);
< undefined
> myArray[0] = 300;
< 300
> myArray[0] & 0xFF
< 44
> (myArray[0] >> 8) & 0xFF
< 1
```